# How do I create multiple answers in the output?

Tags: c, output

I have written a small bit of code that computes on equation for the given number, x. But, when I want to try and duplicate this code it doesn't work. It says "redeclaration of result with no linkage." What I want to do is make an output in the console for when x=0, x=10 and x=-10. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>    
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
  float x = 0.0, result;
  result = 1/(1+exp(x));
  printf("Exponential of %f = %f", x, result);
  return 0;
}
```

It works for just one, but when I duplicate it won't work. What I want to do is just duplicate that so it outputs three calculations for the numbers in the console. Thank you <3

Comment: When asking about a code with error it is imperative that you provide a proper [mcve] in the question, i.e. the *code that produces the error*, and the verbatim error text including the line number and the possible position within the line where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

"redeclaration" means you make copy of line

```
 float x = 0.0, result;
```

if you want just to make from

```
float x = 0.0, result;
result = 1/(1+exp(x));
printf("Exponential of %f = %f", x, result);
```

something to calculate result for different `x`, jut make as follows:

```
float x = 0.0, result; // declaration - only once
result = 1/(1+exp(x));
printf("Exponential of %f = %f", x, result);
x = 0.5; // new value for the same variable
result = 1/(1+exp(x)); // new value for the same variable
printf("Exponential of %f = %f", x, result);
```

Also consider making of loop to exclude copying the code. Common approach is like:

1. Decide when you can take values of `x`: it can be users input or taking values from range from `start` to `end` values.
2. Depending on the decision on step 1 you can select number of iteration in your loop a approach (condition) for stopping the loop.
3. So then select on of loop operators: `for`, `while` or `do{}while` and write the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
float x = 0.0
printf("Exponential of %f = %f\n", x, 1/(1+exp(x));

x = 10.0
printf("Exponential of %f = %f\n", x, 1/(1+exp(x));

x = -10.0
printf("Exponential of %f = %f\n", x, 1/(1+exp(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

In c language, you cannot **redeclare** a variable, but you can **re-assign** variable.

### Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>    
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
  float x = 0.0, result;
  result = 1/(1+exp(x));
  printf("Exponential of %f = %f\n", x, result);

  x=10.0;
  result = 1/(1+exp(x));
  printf("Exponential of %f = %f\n", x, result);

  x=-10.0;
  result = 1/(1+exp(x));
  printf("Exponential of %f = %f\n", x, result);

  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: You cannot reinitialize either, but you can *reassign*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry, my bad.